# How do I pass a Treeview's SelectedItem to another command?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, binding

I created a treeview in WPF MVVM with a hierarchical DAtaTemplate property.

Outside of the Treeview, I have an "EDIT" button. On press of edit button I want to pass the Treeview's selectedItem to the RelayCommand in the viewmodel.

I am implementing the same functionality within the TreeviewItem on double click of the node. However I want to know what is the best way to accomplish this outside.

My code structure is as follows

MainView -> MainViewModel

StateViewItem -> StateViewModel (HierarchicalDataTemplate inheriting from TreeViewItemViewModel)

RegionViewItem -> RegionViewModel (DataTemplate inheriting from TreeViewItemViewModel)

The RegionViewModel handles the double click for the node and accomplishes the Edit functionality.

However the "EDIT" button is outside of the treeview, how do I pass the selected RegionViewItem to the Command bound so I can load it for editing?

thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `RegionViewModel` have access to the `StateViewModel`? Or more importantly, to `StateViewModel.SelectedItem`? (Some code would be helpful)

If not, you may have to implement an event system where whenever `StateViewModel.SelectedItem` changes, it broadcasts a `StateChanged` event, and `RegionViewModel` subscribes to that event and keeps track of the `SelectedState`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! The RegionViewModel has a parent property where it has access to StateViewModel. The StateViewModel has a Children property which is a collection of RegionViewModel. I am not allowed to post project code, but if you need I will create a repro and post it

Comment: I think I mis-read your question... Do you have two editing methods, one in RegionViewModel which works on double-click and one in MainViewModel(?) that should work on Button Click?

Comment: I have one editing method in RegionViewModel which Passes a message to another view model for loading the region for editing.

In the MainViewModel, I want to access the RegionViewModel object which is selected in the Treeview so I can pass the message to load the region for editing

Comment: Can either your `MainViewModel` access the `StateViewModel` or the `MainView` access the `TreeView`? It would be easiest if you could draw the XAML layout or ViewModel hierarchy in pseudocode in the question.

Comment: Hi I used Messaging in MVVM Light to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Code below is ONLY for guidance purposes for MVVM. It may / may not compile.

Way 1:

Assuming that your `TreeViewItemViewModel` is the base item level view model data context for all tree view items in your tree, add a writeable property in `TreeViewItemViewModel` called `IsSelected`. Dont forget to notify property changes in `IsSelected`'s Setter.

In your XAML Tree View add the following in the `Style` targetted for the `TreeViewItem` ....

```
  <TreeView.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      </Style> 
  </TreeView.Resources>
```

This way when any TreeView gets selected, ONLY its own `TreeViewItemViewModel`'s `IsSelected` property will be true and rest all tree view items will be false. So the task left would be to find the selected `TreeViewItemViewModel` object from the hierarchy of object bound to the `ItemsSource` of the `TreeView`.

Way 2:

Have an attached property for a TreeViewItem and handle its MouseDown event. Check if the 'IsSelected' value of the TreeViewItem is true and extract its data context which will be the selected `TreeViewItemViewModel`.

```
  <TreeView.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
          <Setter Property="local:MyAttachedBehavior.HandleMouseDown" Value="true" />
      </Style> 
  </TreeView.Resources>
```

in the static HandleMouseDownPropertyChanged() dependency property changed method, handle the MouseDown event on the `(TreeViewItem)sender` ...

```
  ((TreeViewItem)sender).MouseDown += TreeViewMouseDownEventHandler;

  private static TreeViewMouseDownEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
      var treeViewItem = (TreeViewItem)sender;
      if (treeViewItem.IsSelected)
      {
            var mySelectedItem = treeViewItem.DataContext as TreeViewItemViewModel; 
      } 
  }
```

Pass this selected `TreeViewItemViewModel' instance as the required selected item to your routine.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks I am trying the Way1 now. Will let you know if it works